# How to search through JSON object for specific list o expected key values?

Tags: python, list

I have this json object, and I am curious how to iterate through servicecatalog:name and alert for any name that does not equal "service-foo" or "service-bar".

Here is my json object:

```
{
    "access": {
        "serviceCatalog": [
            {
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "internalURL": "https://snet-storage101.example.com//v1.0", 
                        "publicURL": "https://storage101.example.com//v1.0", 
                        "region": "LON", 
                        "tenantId": "1
                    }, 
                    {
                        "internalURL": "https://snet-storage101.example.com//v1.0", 
                        "publicURL": "https://storage101.example.com//v1.0", 
                        "region": "USA", 
                        "tenantId": "1
                    }
                ], 
                "name": "service-foo", 
                "type": "object-store"
            }, 
            {
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "publicURL": "https://x.example.com:9384/v1.0/x", 
                        "tenantId": "6y5t4re32"
                    }
                ], 
                "name": "service-bar", 
                "type": "rax:test"
            }, 
            {
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "publicURL": "https://y.example.com:9384/v1.0/x", 
                        "tenantId": "765432"
                    }
                ], 
                "name": "service-thesystem", 
                "type": "rax:test"
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: You have an errors in your JSON `"tenantId": "1` is missing `"` at the end and missing `}` at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

If x is the above mentioned dictionary. You could do

```
for item in x["access"]["serviceCatalog"]:
    if item["name"] not in ["service-foo", "service-bar"]:
        print(item["name"])
```

ps: you could use json.loads() to decode json data if you are asking for that. And also you have errors in your JSON.